# Guess the word. I am abundant

Tags: word

Here are some hints.

> I am bright and mostly light.
>   I don't talk unless I'm asked to.
>   If you split me in half, I become a place where people can sit.
>   The other half is a place where everyone wants to be.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really think this is the expected answer, but it sounds good to me :)
You are:

> A laptop

Because:
I am bright and mostly light.

> Laptop screen is generating light

I don't talk unless I'm asked to.

> It remains silent, until you turn the appropriate program on to "talk" for it

If you split me in half, I become a place where people can sit.

> One can sit on somebody's **lap**

The other half is a place where everyone wants to be.

> Everyone wants to be on the **top**

And

> Laptops are quite abundant. (as in title)

Comment: `The other half is a place where everyone wants to be` the explanation made me laugh :D

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind :)

Comment: If you split me in half, I become a place where people can sit. You then say "One can sit on somebodies lap". Isn't that the wrong way round? You are saying that the laptop sits on the lap, whereas the puzzle is saying that the object can be sat on.